# ionic statusbar.styleDefault() isn't working on andorid

Tags: ionic-framework, statusbar, android-statusbar

I want to have a white status bar with black font in my white theme. the problem is that the `styleDefault()` method which is made for it does not work. But this error only happens on Android on Ios it works perfectly. Is there any way to change the font color to black on the statusbar (only for android) or to change it with css? Or how can i make `styleDefault()` (dark text, for light backgrounds) work again?

Here is my code:

```
private setStatusBarStyle(darkTheme: boolean) {
   if (darkTheme) {
     this.statusBar.styleLightContent();
   } else {
     this.statusBar.styleDefault();
   }
}
```

Comment: Seems, you can't set color for text but you can set color for the status bar background: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar#methods

Comment: @DanilProkhorenko yes I know but the problem ist that `styleDefault();`  is not working on android

Comment: "Seems, you can't set color for text but you can set color for the status bar background:" That's not accurate. `StatusBar.styleDefault` and `StatusBar.styleLightContent` are both text color methods. Default is dark text, lightContent is white text. But it's not working for me anymore in Android 11.